# A mo-Roman sampler

Tags: no-computers, formation-of-numbers

Pluck some relatively easy mo-Roman
mini-puzzles while there’s relatively easy pickin’s.

1. > **What two English words, taken as mo-Roman numerals,
   >     form the same number?**

   Two words *other than* **MILL** and **MIC**, that is,
   which both form the number **1099** as an example.

   **MILL**    =   **M** + (−**I** ) + **L** + **L**
               =    1000 − 1 + 50 + 50
               =    **1099**

    
          
   **MIC**    
               =    **M** + (−**I** ) + **C**
                    
               =    1000 − 1 + 100
                
               =    **1099**

   **Mo-Roman numerals** use the same digits as
   [Roman numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals)
   but allow infinite variation.
    
   All digits may occur any number of times and in any order.
   A smaller digit counts negatively
   each time it occurs anywhere to the left of a larger digit.
    
   Here are two more ways to form 1099.

   IDIDCI      =    (−I ) + D +
                                  (−I ) + D + C + I
                   
               =    −1 + 500 - 1 + 500 + 100 + 1
                
               =  1099

    
    
   LVMCLIIII   =    (−L) +
                                  (−V) + M + C + L + I + I + I + I
               =    −50−5+1000+100+50+1+1+1+1
               =  1099

   Among variations of the number that solves this mini-puzzle
   are an everyday word
   and a somewhat technical (not technological) term
   that also spells a common abbreviation.
2. > **What is the *simplest* mo-Roman representation of zero?**
   >     (Meant to familiarize, not trick.)

   ***Simplest*** ?
    
   The fewer the digits the simpler
   (M is simpler than XX).
    
   For the same number of digits,
   compare largest digits
   (LXLI is simpler than VVCI because L is less than C).
    
   Any further ambiguity is decided by persuasive ranting.
3. > **What is the *simplest* mo-Roman numeral
   >     whose value remains unchanged
   >     by removing its last digit?**
   >     (Meant to be more interesting than tricky.)

   A nonsolution,
   going from I**V** to I by removing **V**,
   fails because the value changes (from 4 to 1).
4. > **What is the simplest positive mo-Roman numeral
   >     whose value is negated
   >     by removing its *first* digit?**

   A nonsolution, going from 
   **V**I I I I I IV = 4 
   to 
   I I I I I IV = −1 
   by removing **V**,
   fails because  −4 ≠ −1.
5. > **What is the simplest positive mo-Roman numeral
   >     whose value is negated
   >     by removing its *last* digit?**

   A nonsolution, going from 
   I I I I I IV**V** = 4 
   to 
   I I I I I IV = −1 
   by removing **V**,
   fails because  −4 ≠ −1.
6. > **What is the simplest positive mo-Roman numeral
   >     whose value can be negated
   >     by appending a single digit?**

   A nonsolution, going from 
   I I I I I I = 6 
   to 
   I I I I I I**V** = −1 
   by appending **V**,
   fails because  −6 ≠ −1.
7. > **What is the simplest positive mo-Roman numeral
   >     whose value can be negated
   >     by *prepending* (adding on the left) a single digit?**

   A nonsolution, going from 
   I I I I I IX = 4 
   to 
   **V**I I I I I IX = −1 
   by prepending **V**,
   fails because  −4 ≠ −1.
8. > **What is the simplest positive mo-Roman numeral
   >     whose value is negated
   >     by reversing the order of its digits?**

   A nonsolution, reversing 
   VI I I I I I = 11 
   to get 
   I I I I I IV = −1 ,
   fails because  −11 ≠ −1.
9. > **What is the simplest mo-Roman representation of zero that
   >     
   > • is asymmetric
   >     
   > • also represents zero when reversed?**

   A nonsolution,
   VVVVXX = 0, fails
   because its reverse,
   XXVVVV = 40, does not represent 0.
10. > **What is the simplest mo-Roman representation of zero that
    >     
    > • is asymmetric
    >     
    > • also represents zero when reversed
    >     
    > • includes only one instance of its largest digit?**

    The same nonsolution,
    VVVVXX = 0, fails both
    because its reverse does not represent 0
    and because it contains *two* instances of its largest digit, X.
11. > **What is the simplest mo-Roman representation of zero that
    >     
    > • is asymmetric
    >     
    > • also represents zero when reversed
    >     
    > • includes only one instance of its largest digit
    >     
    > • begins and ends with different digits?**

    That nonsolution,
    VVVVXX = 0,
    does begin and end with different digits, V and X,
    but again fails
    because its reverse does not represent 0
    and it contains two instances of its largest digit.

Pick and pluck as you please.
 
Partial posts are welcome.
 
The mo-Roman the mo-merrier!

Comment: Is the empty string a solution to #2?

Comment: Ohohoho, @Deusovi, don't make me edit the puzzle statement to exclude answers that would also work for standard Roman numerals, or that would rewrite mathematical history. (Sorry for the after-edit-period re-comment but:) Now I'm seeing mo-Roman 0s everywhere!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1 What two English words, taken as mo-Roman numerals, form the same number?

> **IM**(apparently can be used as a noun) and **DID** = 999
>  
>  [[Intended answer, from Dan Russell: **DIM** = **ID** = 499]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51390/18129)

2 What is the simplest mo-Roman representation of zero?

> I believe the simplest/smallest answer is **VVX** because V being half of X is the best ratio to nullify the value quickly.

3 What is the simplest mo-Roman numeral whose value remains unchanged by removing its last digit?

> **VX** removing the last X still gives 5.

4 What is the simplest positive mo-Roman numeral whose value is negated by removing its first digit?

> **XVVVX** remove the first X and it goes from 5 to -5

5 What is the simplest positive mo-Roman numeral whose value is negated by removing its last digit?

> **VVVXX** remove the last X and it goes from 5 to -5

6 What is the simplest positive mo-Roman numeral whose value can be negated by appending a single digit?

> **VVVXVV** appending a X will go from 5 to -5

7 What is the simplest positive mo-Roman numeral whose value can be negated by prepending (adding on the left) a single digit?

> **LLCV** goes from 5 to -5 by prepending a X

8 What is the simplest positive mo-Roman numeral whose value is negated by reversing the order of its digits?

> **XVVVVXV** reverting the order will make it go from 5 to -5

9 What is the simplest mo-Roman representation of zero that
• is asymmetric
• also represents zero when reversed?

> Yet again, not sure if the best but... **VVCLLLLCX**

10 What is the simplest mo-Roman representation of zero that
• is asymmetric
• also represents zero when reversed
• includes only one instance of its largest digit?

> Seems a bit long, but maybe **VIIIIIIIIIIXV** is the best...

11 What is the simplest mo-Roman representation of zero that
• is asymmetric
• also represents zero when reversed
• includes only one instance of its largest digit
• begins and ends with different digits?

> Assuming 10 is correct, perhaps **XVVVVVVVVVVLVV** is the best.

Comment: @humn thanks. I will try to fix my 6 now... that was a silly mistake of me.

Comment: @humn ah! found the number 3.... so easy... how could I have been so blind >.<

Comment: What a recovery on #6 as well, stack reader!  If this doesn't get more attention otherwise (and maybe even if it does) you'll get a bounty. (Or maybe that'll be a way to get you to find another #1 . . .) (And thank you for going to the trouble of copying alllll the puzzle statements.)

Comment: @humn thanks. You can delay the answered check for as long as you want... It would be a shame this original puzzle doesn't get any more attention. I know the feeling. My last puzzle took me 4 hours to make and got like 50 views haha....

Comment: Yes, that feeling, stack reader. You made up for your last puzzle today, though, by solving this one in much less time than it took me just to decide how to mix mo-Roman explanation into this puzzle. You'll also be the most prepared solver for future spin-offs (2 in the works that will lean on this one, at some point).

Comment: 10 is indeed the optimal solution. You can note that to subtract from that biggest number, you cannot use 1 class smaller number, as it cannot work reversed (say VX becomes XV). And 2 class smaller numbers always have factor of 10 between them. So you always need the shape of V_____X_____V with 10 I anywhere between Vs (as long as it isn't 5 on each side).

Comment: Why not undelete your answer, @Zizy Archer, and restate it as "backpuzzle" entries #12 and #13 of the original puzzle, keeping the solutions hidden?  (_Backpuzzle_ is like backwash, for puzzles, in a good-humoured sense.) Your insights would help make mo-Roman numerals all the mo-understandable. And I wanted to include negative-to-positive mini-puzzles all along but thought it would make the overall effect even more unwieldy.

Comment: A simpler one for #6 is $VVVX=-5$.  Add $X$ to get $VVVXX=5$.  Same solution works for #7.  $XVVVX=5$ as well.

Comment: @Trenin the mo roman must be positive. So -5 is not accepted.

Comment: @stackreader Huh.  Missed that when I read it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For mini-puzzle #1, how about

> **DIM** = -500 -1 +1000 = **499**
>
>  and
>
>  **ID** = -1 +500 = **499** (as in Freud)